# UML Partitioning Decision Nodes

Tags: uml, modeling, diagrams

I am attempting to partition a decision node based on environment attributes. The process I am modeling is slightly different depending if a variable scope is public or private.

I am trying to associate the related `Map Variables` action in the `Pipeline` partition but cannot determine the best way to model this. Should I use a fork node only for this specific action or instead add the action for both decision flows into the existing `Pipeline` partition?

[image]

Comment: You want to use object nodes instead. Your decision is not a hexagon but a diamond shaped element (so not correct UML).

Comment: It looks OK to me. If you want to use swimlanes (it's ugly) have a look at https://www.planttext.com/?text=TP4nRuCm48Nt-nKtXgNTOGdAaAL8I4YfEXvmAQSQsx8DKYJ_-1WIgb2fgz_TUzyz7tqW5wPH0SIAH4TO7m3oapAQyQnCI-hjGaweLUpHiJLUWd6t0a2kUDWaR3fZESCmiCQ3TJ9Ju0nY-Tb4oCk-n_av2S5WJOv6R98F5n2_okhZERGAi0eu23jotP2YOYsMbMXEOnNPNoyFefCTwrcSqIFh0BCG-iw93GNaPmuxovdKj2G-RcNbER5EhP8kss5i_lZ3j_TjwJy6N1ZWXG5V6ROitSirzLfFVi3JGFexmIVqlmt3hc4VZ0KufkNbZ-u0

Comment: By the way, I got back the PlantUML source from your imgur PNG using http://exif.regex.info/exif.cgi

Comment: @qwerty_so PlantUML puts the decision in the diamond making it a hexagon.

Comment: @Fuhrmanator I thought so (seen that in another question). Doesn't make it right, though.

Comment: @Fuhrmanator, using swimlanes is a potential alternative although I agree not the most elegant solution. I wasn't sure if there was a preferred method I was overlooking, I'm glad to see that doesn't appear to be the case. Additionally, I did not realize PlantUML source code is saved into the image source, thanks for the info.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Rather than swim lanes (which are purely graphical annotations) you would use Partitions which are concrete UML elements. You can classify these partitions (e.g. with components representing the environment in question).

[image]

Further I suggest to use Pins and an ObjectFlow where objects (like the YAML) are sent along actions.